# execute multiple batch file from VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to execute multiple batch files in a folder using vbscript. can anyone help me how to do it.
Here is my code.

```
 Varr1 = hostname
 UN = username
 password = pass
set ObjFSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     set FilePath = ObjFSO.getfolder("C:\test\script")
     set BatFile = FilePath.files

     for each m in BatFile
      If LCase(objFSO.GetExtension(FilePath.files)) = "bat" Then
         Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
         WShell.Run ("CMD /K C:\test\script "&BatFile &" " & Varr1 &" "& UN &" "& password )
      End If
    Next
```

Comment: So, what is the issue with that code?

Comment: My code is not executing the Batch files

Answer (score 1):

Given .BAT files like:

```
@echo off
echo a, $1, $2
```

in the current directory, a .VBS like:

```
Option Explicit

Const u = "user"
Const p = "passw"

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim goWS : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim f, c
For Each f In goFS.GetFolder(".\").Files 
    If "bat" = goFS.GetExtensionName(f.Name) Then
        c = Join(Array("%comspec%", "/K", f.Name, u, p)) 
        WScript.Echo "will call", c
        goWS.Run c
    End If
Next
```

will execute all of them in new consoles.

output:

```
cscript 47609016.vbs
will call %comspec% /K b.bat user passw
will call %comspec% /K a.bat user passw
```

(and some windows containing something like "a 'user' 'passw'")